# Memory Operations in Release Semantics - Memory Ordering of C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand `Acquire-Release Semantics` of C++11 Memory Ordering.

What I don't understand is whether the following asserts will ever fail:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

int global_x{0};
std::atomic_int sync{0};
std::atomic_int atm_y{0};

void thread1()
{
    global_x=100;
    atm_y.store(200, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    sync.store(1,std::memory_order_release);
}

void thread2()
{
    while(!sync.load(std::memory_order_acquire)){;}
    assert(atm_y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 200);
    assert(global_x == 100);
}

int main()
{
    global_x=0;
    sync=0;
    atm_y=0;
    std::thread t1(thread1);
    std::thread t2(thread2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I know `sync.store()` will `synchronize-with` `sync.load()` because of the `acquire-release semantics` but does this semantics guarantee that the memory operations preceding `release` will go into the memory(RAM) ?

Comment: [Off Topic] `while(!sync.load(std::memory_order_acquire)){;}` can be replaced with a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and using the `wait` and `notify_all` functions.  This should be less CPU intensive then a infinite loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver [Off Topic] I am just an innocent soul trying to understand these fundamentals :)

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing a very similar example (Listing 5.8) from "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams:

The assert on the load from atm_y will never fail because the store to atm_y happens-before the store to sync (they're in the same thread). Because the store to sync synchronizes-with the load from sync, the store to atm_y also happens-before the load from sync and by extension happens-before the load from atm_y.

The same logic applies to the assignment to global_x. The assignment happens-before the store to sync so the assert will never fire.